# resolve dependencies from workspace projects in IDEA

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea, ide

I used to work in Eclipse, and i know how i can activate this settings there. How can I do it in IDEA?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically the default setting in IntelliJ IDEA. However, this applies only to Maven modules within the same IntelliJ project (window). When importing multiple Maven modules, IntelliJ often suggests creating a separate IntelliJ project for each, so this can be confusing. Instead, however, you can just import multiple modules into the same IntelliJ project via:

`File` > `New` > `Module from Existing Sources...`

Or you can achieve the same result by using a `+` button in `Maven Projects` sidebar.